# Preload ManyToMany relations with Doctrine

Tags: performance, doctrine-orm, query-builder, relationships, preload

I've some problems trying to preload ManyToMany relations. I have People in relation with Segments; People belong to Groups, and when I load a Group I want to preload all his People with theyrs Segments.

Here's the (simplified) mappings:

**Group:**

```
Cerebrum\ORM\GroupEntity:
  type: entity
  table: groups
  id:
    uuid:
      type: integer
      column: id
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
      options: { unsigned: true }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 200
      unique: true
      column: group_name
  manyToMany:
    people:
      targetEntity: Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity
      cascade: ["persist"]
      mappedBy: groups
```

**Person:**

```
Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity:
  type: entity
  table: persons
  id:
    uuid:
      type: integer
      column: id
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
      options: { unsigned: true }
  fields:
    username:
      type: string
      length: 50
      nullable: true
      unique: true
  manyToMany:
    groups:
      targetEntity: Cerebrum\ORM\GroupEntity
      cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
      inversedBy: people
      joinTable:
        name: groups_persons
        joinColumns:
          person_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: CASCADE
        inverseJoinColumns:
          group_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: CASCADE
    segments:
      targetEntity: Cerebrum\ORM\SegmentEntity
      cascade: ["persist"]
      inversedBy: people
      joinTable:
        name: segments_persons
        joinColumns:
          person_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: CASCADE
        inverseJoinColumns:
          segment_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: CASCADE
```

**Segment:**

```
Cerebrum\ORM\SegmentEntity:
  type: entity
  table: segments
  id:
    uuid:
      type: integer
      column: id
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
      options: { unsigned: true }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 200
      unique: true
      column: segment_name
  manyToMany:
    people:
      targetEntity: Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity
      cascade: ["persist"]
      mappedBy: segments
```

When I load a group I try this approach:

```
<?php
$builder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select('p,s')
    ->from('Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('Cerebrum\ORM\SegmentEntity', 's')
    ->where('p.uuid IN (:persone)');
$builder->setParameter('persone', $this->entity->getPeople());
$query = $builder->getQuery();
```

If I try `$query->getDQL()` I get `SELECT p,s FROM Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity p LEFT JOIN Cerebrum\ORM\SegmentEntity s WHERE p.uuid IN (:persone)`, and if I cycle through `$query->getResult()` I obtain a list of PersonEntity and SegmentEntity. The problem is that PersonEntities don't have theyr relations loaded, as you can see in this dump:

```
Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity {#427
  -uuid: 1
  -username: "argonauta"
  -segments: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#464
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: Cerebrum\ORM\PersonEntity {#427}
    -association: array:20 [ …20]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#108 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "people"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#428 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#465
      -elements: []
    }
    #initialized: false
  }
}
```

This cause A LOT of queries to database, because each Person load his Segments with a single query. I know I'll need all these informations, so preloading them with a single query is my choice.

Do you have any hint for me? I spent all the morning googling :-(